# Calculate percentages like Excel pie chart

Tags: excel, pie-chart

I'm translating a calculation model from Excel to a programming language, and I'd like to keep the results as similar to the Excel ones as possible.

Specifically, I want to make sure pie chart percentages add up to 100 when they're displayed as whole numbers.

Example:

- consider the set: `[ 7, 13, 58, 43 ]`.
- The percentages in a pie charts should be `[ 5.79%, 10.74%, 47.93%, 35.54% ]`
- Round the numbers and you get `[ 6%, 11%, 48%, 36% ]`. These add up to 101.
- According to [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214033), Excel should subtract 1 percent from the largest number.
- That information doesn't apply to Excel 2007 apparently, since the actual numbers that I'm seeing are `[ 6%, 11%, 48%, 35% ]`, so it subtracted 1 from the second-largest number.

I found [this page](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/pie-chart-rounding-in-excel/) that seems to acknowledge that the situation is weird, but doesn't really have the algorithm Excel uses.

**EDIT**: I missed it the first time, but that page implies that "the internal mechanism Excel uses minimizes the error in the percentages in a similar manner to the way a least squares minimizes the error between a data set and the regression line that describes it". Not sure if it's just a wild guess or something more.

Can anyone shed a light on the matter?

(Obligatory link: [Save the Pie for Dessert](http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/08-21-07.pdf))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it will subtract 1 from the number with the smallest decimal part equal to or larger than 0,5%. In this case the second largest number has only 0,54%, the others all have something larger.

Example:

[image: example rounded total of 101]

Also, when your total goes to 99%, you should pick the value with the largest decimal part smaller than 0,5%.

Example:

[image: example rounded total of 101]

So create your algorithm accordingly.